# Hierarchical rollup of sales data based on parent - child relationship, in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, hierarchical-data

I have a Dataframe that has sales data by each sales person as shown below:

```
employee, product, quantity
emp_1, prod_a, 100
emp_1, prod_b, 200
emp_2, prod_a, 30
emp_4, prod_c, 400    
emp_4, prod_a, 100
```

I have another Dataframe that have the team hierarchy

```
employee, manager
emp_1, emp_3
emp_2, emp_3
emp_3, emp_4   
emp_4, emp_5
```

I am trying to create this master Dataframe that has the sales done by every employee an also maps the manager that respective employee reports to

```
employee, product, quantity, manager
emp_1, prod_a, 100, emp_3
emp_1, prod_b, 200, emp_3
emp_2, prod_a, 30, emp_3
emp_1, prod_a, 100, emp_4
emp_1, prod_b, 200, emp_4
emp_2, prod_a, 30, emp_4
emp_4, prod_c, 400, emp_5
emp_4, prod_a, 100, emp_5
emp_1, prod_a, 100, emp_5
emp_1, prod_b, 200, emp_5
emp_2, prod_a, 30, emp_5
```

Basically every manager inherits their sub-ordinates numbers and also their numbers if they sales under their name.

Comment: Interesting. But can you explain the discrepancies if you look at say `sales[sales['employee'] == 'emp_1']`, why us the 'manager' for emp_1 being variously reported as emp_3, emp_4, emp_5 in different rows, and how are to handle that in the rollup? Or just ignore `sales['manager']` column entirely and only use the manager as defined in `hierarchy` table?

Comment: If I understand correctly, emp_3's manager is emp_4 and emp_4's manager is emp_5. So it's `emp_1 -> emp_3 -> emp_4 -> emp_5` up the hierarchy chain. The final table is to include _all_ managers up the chain per employee. The question I do have, though, is why `emp_1, prod_a, 100, emp_5` appears twice in the result set.

Comment: @smci as @Henry mentioned an employee's actuals get cascaded to every manager above him and hence you see actuals of `emp_1` mapped to every manager of `emp_3` his actual manager. Hope this clarified

Comment: @HenryEcker that is a duplicate guess my mistake when I tried re-creating the sample output. I will have that updated..

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that this could be solved with `networkx`, but I'm not familiar with the package to assert. However, you could try this solution and see if it fits your use case:

Get a combination/zip of `employee` and `manager` in the second dataframe:

```
zipped = zip(df2.employee, df2.manager)
zipped = [(first, last, int(last[-1])) for first, last in zipped]
```

Get the maximum value for the last entry per tuple:

```
from operator import itemgetter # cleaner if this is at the top
maximum = max(zipped, key = itemgetter(-1))[-1]
```

Use the maximum to create pairings between employee and managers:

```
mapping = {first : last 
           if num == maximum else 
          [f"emp_{n}" for n in range(maximum, num -1, -1)] 
          for first, last, num in zipped}

mapping
{'emp_1': ['emp_5', 'emp_4', 'emp_3'],
 'emp_2': ['emp_5', 'emp_4', 'emp_3'],
 'emp_3': ['emp_5', 'emp_4'],
 'emp_4': 'emp_5'}
```

`map` mapping to employee and use the resulting data to merge with the first dataframe:

```
df1.merge(df2.assign(manager = df2.employee
                                  .map(mapping))
                                  .explode('manager')
            )

   employee  product   quantity manager
0     emp_1   prod_a        100   emp_5
1     emp_1   prod_a        100   emp_4
2     emp_1   prod_a        100   emp_3
3     emp_1   prod_b        200   emp_5
4     emp_1   prod_b        200   emp_4
5     emp_1   prod_b        200   emp_3
6     emp_2   prod_a         30   emp_5
7     emp_2   prod_a         30   emp_4
8     emp_2   prod_a         30   emp_3
9     emp_4   prod_c        400   emp_5
10    emp_4   prod_a        100   emp_5
```

Comment: thank you this helps map every employee to manager at the first level. However I am still trying to see if we can map data from one manager to their manager one level above. In the given sample data `emp_3` reports to `emp_4` so I am trying to see if we can map all data that is mapped to `emp_3` to also be mapped to `emp_4`. In other words, since `emp_4` is the manager for `emp_3` we are trying to show data of `emp_1` and `emp_2`  to be mapped to `emp_4` and so on